# I am trying to save image with time and date but image is not saving

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save confusion matrix with current time but its not working please help me to save the image.

```
rgb = Image.open("confussion_matrix.jpg")
rgb = np.array(rgb)
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S")
filename = '%s.png' % (current_time)
cv2.imwrite(filename, rgb)
```

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFq39.png)

Comment: **forward slashes**... make sure those **directories** exist, or use something other than slashes if you don't mean to talk about directories. in addition to the caveats mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the image is not saving it's because of the line `current_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S")` where you have `:` is causing the problem. If you should replace `:` with `_` or `-` it should work fine. In addition, cv2.imwrite() method does not throw an error to identify the problem either.

This worked for me just now.

```
rgb = Image.open("confussion_matrix.jpg")
rgb = np.array(rgb)
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
filename = '%s.png' % current_time

if not cv2.imwrite(filename, rgb):
    raise Exception("Could not write image")
```